# John's Statement: Hello, How are you? - Split

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am currently using VB.net and in one of my task I need to compress a file , but I need it to do the following:

For example: John's Statement: Hello, How are you?

This need to split into:

```
1.John  
2.'  
3.s  
4.  
5.Statement  
6.:  
7.   
8.Hello  
9.,  
10.   
11.How  
12.   
13.are  
14.   
15.you  
16.?
```

This is what I have tried:

```
    Dim Sentence As String
    Dim Words() As String

    'Ask user to input a sentence into the system'
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the sentence: ")
    Sentence = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.Clear()

    Words = Regex.Split(Sentence, "(\b[^\s]+\b)")
```

This is what it dies right now:

[Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/6zTpqu/1)

Comment: First, please pick a language. Are you using c# or vb.net? Please don't tag with both. Second, what have you tried so far? We're happy to help you solve your problem, but not do it for you. [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @EdCottrell, Thank you for you comment, I am new to this. Hopefully, the changes I have made are ok : )

Comment: To improve the question now that it has code in it, you explain what you tried, but you don't say what it does now. What does the output look like with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
(?=\b|\W)(?!^)
```

The rest of the code can remain unchanged.

This will not capture any characters. It looks ahead to see if there is a word break or a non-alphabetical/numerical character following. The `(?!^)` will prevent an immediate split at the start of the string.

Comment: What is the difference between using (?=\b|\W)(?!^) and (?=\s|\b)? Just being curious. I am not sure which one to use as i don't know which one would work most effectively...Thanks

Comment: Without the `(?!^)` you'll get an empty string in the first element of your Words array.

Comment: The other difference is minimal: `\s` will split on white space, while `\W` will *also* split before every punctuation, so that for instance a space followed by a punctuation mark (unusual as it is) will also be split into separate elements.

Comment: No, it was an accident.. sorry

Comment: Ah, ok. No problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex `Split` with *Linq* (C# implementation):

```
  string source = "John's Statement: Hello, How are you?";

  var result = Regex
   .Split(source, @"(\W)") // split on non-word letters, preserve splitter
   .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));
```

Test

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select((v, i) => $"{i + 1,2}. {v}")));
```

Outcome:

```
 1. John
 2. '
 3. s
 4.  
 5. Statement
 6. :
 7.  
 8. Hello
 9. ,
10.  
11. How
12.  
13. are
14.  
15. you
16. ?
```

Comment: Hi, would you have i could implement this into VB.net. Sorry, i am quite new to coding. Thank You...

Comment: @Shabs: something like `Dim result = Regex.Split(source, "(\W)").Where(Function(c) Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(c) End Function)`

Answer (score 1):

You can split using a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`), like this:

```
(?=\s|\b)
```

This matches any place that is immediately followed by a space or a boundary.

So, your split command would become:

```
Words = Regex.Split(Sentence, "(?=\s|\b)")
```

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/6zTpqu/2).

Comment: Do you know if there is any code i can use to split the (') as well... Thank You

Comment: @Shabs Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See my corrected version and the updated demo.

Comment: @Shabs awesome; glad to help out!